# How to embed a Google Gadget into a Google Site using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

Hi I'd like to add a Google Gadget to a page through the sites.CreateWebPage() function.  I tried doing this by pasting the code for the gadget into the html part of the function but that doesn't seem to work.

Here is my code:

```
  var aboutSection = '<div><img src="https://www.google.com/chart?chc=sites&amp;cht=d&amp;chdp=sites&amp;chl=%5B%5BGoogle+Apps+Script'%3D20'f%5Cv'a%5C%3D0'10'%3D499'0'dim'%5Cbox1'b%5CF6F6F6'fC%5CF6F6F6'eC%5C0'sk'%5C%5B%22Google+Script+Gadget%22'%5D'a%5CV%5C%3D12'f%5C%5DV%5Cta%5C%3D10'%3D0'%3D500'%3D297'dim'%5C%3D10'%3D10'%3D500'%3D297'vdim'%5Cbox1'b%5Cva%5CF6F6F6'fC%5CC8C8C8'eC%5C'a%5C%5Do%5CLauto'f%5C&amp;sig=6fhWXmnlPoRsJXpVKNfumRBLsmo" style="display: block; text-align: left; " data-props="align:left;showBorder:true;showBorderTitle:true;borderTitle:Google Script Gadget;height:200;objectTitle:About;libId:Mf2G3RE0TBWexGMtAO6CROH-2sYrtNBN4;restrictionMyself:false;restrictionDomain:false;restrictionAnyone:true;allowAnonymous:false" id="7206614969763905" data-type="maestro" class="sites-placeholder-maestro" data-origsrc="https://sites.google.com/a/macros/eyethu.org/exec?service=AKfycbzpyOcUFaYweehTWPn9XwERTfAOPXoBeua2RZ8NVg" width="500" height="300"></div> <div></div>';
  site.createWebPage(name + ' ' + surname, name + '_' + surname, aboutSection);
```

I know the (') quotes are causing problems but I replaced them all with ('') and it's still not working.  It just displays the frame and that missing image icon.

Thanks in advance for your help.

This is what I've done after your suggestion:

```
var templ = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('profile').evaluate();
var tem = templ.getContent();
site.createWebPage(name + ' ' + surname, name + '_' + surname, tem);
```

I got the code by editing the site, copying the html and pasting it into an html file.  It works but it shows the gadgets as the images in the edit page.  I'm obviously doing the template creation wrong is there another way of generating the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to deal with Sites pages with gadgets and other apps scripts in Apps Scripts is to create a 'template' page by hand and make a copy of it in your script code.

1. Create a Google Sites page manually and add the gadgets you need (say page1),
2. Use code similar to this

   var page1 = SitesApp.getPageByUrl('url_of_page1');

   var html = page1.getHtmlContent();

   var site = SitesApp.getSite(url);

   site.createWebPage(title,name, html);

Comment: Could you perhaps give me an example if it's not to much trouble?  I'm not sure how I would for example load three gadgets onto an HTML page using a template.

Comment: I edited my original post to reflect the changes I made per your suggestion.

Comment: I've edited my earlier answer with some rough code snippet you can work with

Comment: I tried it but the page it creates only shows the title of the gadget?

Comment: I think you might be hitting Issue 572 ( http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=572 ). Can you please verify

Comment: Yes, seems to be the same issue after enabling the title and border the gadgets now load.  Thank you for your help!